# Logstash JDBC class cannot found

Tags: logstash

Can you help me to solve this problem
I'm using
elasticsearch-7.4.2
kibana-7.4.2
logstash-7.4.2
windows 10

```
Error: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?
Exception: LogStash::PluginLoadingError
Stack: D:/elasticsearch/logstash-7.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.16/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:190:in open_jdbc_connection' D:/elasticsearch/logstash-7.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.16/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:253:in execute_statement'
D:/elasticsearch/logstash-7.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.16/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:309:in execute_query' D:/elasticsearch/logstash-7.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.16/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:281:in run'
D:/elasticsearch/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:314:in inputworker' D:/elasticsearch/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:306:in block in start_input'
[2019-11-28T15:08:50,858][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline ][main] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
```

my conf

```
input{
jdbc{
jdbc_driver_library => "D:\elasticsearch\mysql-connector-java-8.0.18\mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila"
jdbc_user => ""
jdbc_password => "**"
statement => "SELECT * FROM actor"
}
}
output{
elasticsearch{
hosts => "localhost:9200"
action => "index"
index => "actor"
document_type => 'text'
document_id => '%{id}'
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the relevant mysql jar file to `[logstash_folder]\logstash-core\lib\jars` and provide only the jar name in the config file as follows
`jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar"`